# How can I save a file to a user specific directory flutter Desktop?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I allow the user to save a file to a specific folder in Flutter?
I have built a simple desktop app for Mac that returns a file from an API.
Currently, it saves the file to a caches directory.

```
try {
  io.Directory saveDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String filePath = saveDir.path;
  io.File returnedFile = new io.File('$filePath/$filename.xlsx');
  await returnedFile.writeAsBytes(result.bodyBytes);
  print(saveDir);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I played around with my original code and that provided by @Pavel and managed to write my solution to saving files to a custom user-picked directory in this fashion.

The first part opens a file picker dialogue that returns a path to a directory.

The second part provides the path to the File class that then writes the file to that directory.
Hope this helps anyone trying to save files.

```
String? outputFile = await FilePicker.platform.saveFile(
                      dialogTitle: 'Save Your File to desired location',
                      fileName: filename);
                      
                     
                  try {
                    io.File returnedFile = io.File('$outputFile');
                    await returnedFile.writeAsBytes(responsefile.bodyBytes);
                  } catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

```dart
String? outputFile = await FilePicker.platform.saveFile(
  dialogTitle: 'Please select an output file:',
  fileName: 'output-file.pdf',
);

if (outputFile == null) {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, this function does not actually save a file. It only opens the dialog to let the user choose a location and file name. This function only returns the path to this (non-existing) file. I have been playing around with it trying to see I can send the file along with the function. I will share my findings once I am successful.